# sslforfree альтернатива сертификата на сайт ( для обычных хостингов, не VDS/VPS )

Tags: ssl

```
//0. есть сервис sslforfree
//1. вбиваем домен
//2. выбираем ручная
//3. нужные файлы копируем, ложим на хост, подтверждаем
//4. получаем файлы сертификата
//5. в КП хостинга помещаем файлы сертификата

//готово, вопрос решен без терминала
```

Есть ли альтернатива данному сервису? что бы можно было на самом простом хостинге сделать сертификат?

p.s. Интересует именно сервис, а не доп расширения для контрольных панелей
p.p.s. не letsencrypt, который первый в гугле, но при этом нужно юзать терминал

Comment: Чем вам не угодил терминал? Чем вам не угодил sslforfree? Ничего не понятно

Comment: кнопки люблю больше терминала, т.к. нажатие 1 кнопки это быстрее ввода команды, которую можно еще и не вспомнить. sslforfree - классный, просто охота альтернативу попробовать.

Comment: Вспоминать не надо, надо записывать команды в скрипт, который будет запускаться одной кнопкой ;) А под ваши хотелки вы вряд ли что-то найдёте, всех устраивает терминал (и sslforfree мало кто любит)

Comment: Увы, в 2020 SSLForFree ограничил халяву и теперь выдает только 3 бесплатных сертификата на один аккаунт.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/525368)